# Tax on Wall Street

Tags: united-states, political-theory, taxes

What does Bernie Sanders mean when he says he will impose a tax on Wall Street speculation? What kinds of investments is he talking about? Who defines what is "risky/gambling"?

Comment: I haven't look at it in great details but I think the idea is that it would be a (small) fee per transaction. So if you move your money constantly (i.e. you speculate), you pay more. It's a sliding scale and can even cover yet-to-invent ways to speculate, no need to define what is gambling or to designate specific stocks/instruments/whatever as risky.

Comment: there already is a tax on investment transactions (except for a few tax exempt college and retirement plans), so it would be small additional fee on all investments?

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE. This question is a vivid example why we suggest the askers **to provide with some references** within the questions. See [this Meta post](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/2544/2984) and its answers. Looking at Bernie Sanders' speech(es) and the context of discussion, it may become more apparent what he means. Don't let us Google for you! :-)

Comment: I want to support what bytebuster said. This question can easily be answered by going to Bernie Sander's own campaign website, following the links, and doing some subsequent Google searches.

Answer (score 2):

> what does Bernie Sanders mean when he says he will impose a tax on wall street speculation? what kinds of investments is he talking about?

Bernie Sanders wants to enact a financial transactions tax like what exists in the UK and what was proposed by House Speaker Jim Wright and had bipartisan support after the stock market crash of 1987.

His [campaign website](https://berniesanders.com/issues/how-bernie-pays-for-his-proposals/) links to [this paper](http://www.peri.umass.edu/fileadmin/pdf/ftt/Pollin--Heintz--Memo_on_FTT_Rates_and_Revenue_Potential_w_references----6-9-12.pdf) when it refers to his Wall Street speculation tax. It describes a tax on the trading of stocks, bonds, and derivatives. For stocks, the tax would be 0.5% of the value of the stock trade. For bonds, 0.15%, and for derivatives, 0.005%. This is estimated to produce $300 billion in revenue, which is intended to pay for free college for all, and substantially reduce student debt.

The paper also refers to [another paper](http://www.peri.umass.edu/fileadmin/pdf/research_brief/PERI_FTT_Research_Brief.pdf) that provides further information on the tax.

> who defines what is "risky/gambling"?

This seems to be a non sequitur and I don't know how to answer except by saying it is widely accepted that speculation and high-frequency trading of the sort that would be discouraged by the tax are considered risky trading behaviors. For example, the Securities and Exchange Commission and the Commodity Futures Trade Commission jointly [determined](http://www.sec.gov/news/studies/2010/marketevents-report.pdf) that high-frequency trading contributed to the 2010 crash. A Google search returns a large number of articles that attempts to explain why these behaviors are considered risky.

[How High-Speed Trading Fuels Wall Street Disasters](http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2013/02/high-frequency-trading-danger-risk-wall-street)

[Regulators Sound Alarm on High-Frequency Trading Firms](http://www.wsj.com/articles/regulators-sound-alarm-on-high-frequency-trading-firms-1430414889)

[How to avoid another market crash](http://fortune.com/2015/09/02/stock-market-volatility-china/)

Bernie Sander's campaign website contains a [FAQ with further information about his wall street speculation tax plan](http://feelthebern.org/bernie-sanders-on-financial-regulation/#tax-on-wall-street). His website is very well sourced and should be the first place anyone checks when they want to know detailed information about his ideas.

Comment: Note: They tried this in Sweden in the 80's. Didn't work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_financial_transaction_tax

Answer (score 1):

Sanders proposed a tax on financial transactions often called Tobin taxes or [robin hood taxes](http://www.robinhoodtax.org/news/blog/sen-bernie-sanders-officially-introduces-robin-hood-tax-act). Sanders's proposal "[calls for](http://www.ocregister.com/articles/tax-705122-trading-transaction.html) 0.5 percent on stock trades, 0.1 percent on bond trades and 0.005 percent on derivatives."

The idea is that if you're engaging in "safe" investment where you put your 401k or IRA into an index fund, then the tax burden is very low. It will make the returns on these investments go down a bit, as it will be more expensive to make trades to maintain a big index, but presumably they will not go down all that much. Managed mutual funds will be hit a little harder, as the investors behind them will have to pay taxes on each trade they make to change the composition of the fund based on their analysis. The tax does get very high, however, for quick speculative investing or day trading. If you move around $10,000 per day in speculative trades and are taxed at Sanders's 0.5%, then you'll be taxed $18,250 over the course of a year. Thus the tax discourages that kind of speculation. Rapid trading strategies that seek to take advantage of small fluctuations in stock prices would have to be much more wary of risk, since each trade is suddenly more costly.

There are [concerns](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-10-05/europe-s-robin-hood-tax-is-a-risky-proposal) that this kind of tax will not raise total tax revenue (the idea is that there will be a reduction in total gdp). There are also concerns that it will not prevent the kind of speculation that led up to the 2008 financial crisis: "The tax wouldn't have much effect on mortgage bonds or complex derivatives, which trade infrequently and which were largely responsible for exacerbating the credit crisis. Instead, it would mostly apply to currencies, equities, futures and options, which trade more actively." Remember, it's not how risky the investment is that matters, so much as how quickly you want to trade it away when it comes to this kind of tax.